# How to create drop-down list with dynamic values in Mule connector

Tags: mule

I know there is a way to create dropdown list using enum(it is also mentioned here [how do i add a drop down list item in a mule connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473105/how-do-i-add-a-drop-down-list-item-in-a-mule-connector)), but in that case the enum is pre-defined already, you know the values.
What if I don't know the values ahead, for example the dropdown list needs to take values from an API call. How could I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that using DataSense, but in a hackish way since you are only going to use the keys and retrieve the same entity for all the keys.

I suggest you to read the [DataSense Docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/adding-datasense) if you are not fammiliar with it.

Example:

```
@MetadataCategory
public class DropDownCategory(){

    // this method output will be displayed as a dropdown list
    @MetaDataKeyRetriever
    public List<MetaDataKey> getMetaDataKeys() throws Exception {
        List<MetaDataKey> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        // Fill your list with the data of the ap
        // new DefaultMetaDataKey(id, value));
        return keys;
    }

    @MetaDataRetriever
    public MetaData getMetaData(MetaDataKey key) throws Exception {
        // here you will retrieve the same entity for all the keys (or not, depending what you want to implement)
        return new DefaultMetaData(...);
    }

}
```

Finally you will need to anotate your processor with `@MetaDataScope(DropDownCategory.class)` and the parameter that you want to be represented as a DropDown List with `@MetaDataKeyParam`

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the doc, looks like this is what I want. Will test and comment again.

Comment: There is a limitation for this method though. For one operation, there is only one parameter that we can apply @MetaDataKeyParam, that is only one parameter can see dynamic values.